# deleteRow Não deleta totalmente a linha da tabela

Tags: javascript, html

Segue minha função javascript que deveria excluir permanentemente uma linha:

```
function deletaItemExtra(item){

            var x = document.getElementById(item);

            x.deleteCell(1);

            x.deleteCell(0);

            document.getElementById(item).deleteRow;

            if(document.getElementById(item) != null){

                alert('Ainda é encontrado no sistema'); 

            }else{

                alert('Foi totalmente deletado do sistema'); 

            }

        }
```

O problema é que quando vou verificar as linhas, esta que deveria ter sido deletada, ainda consta na table. Por este motivo coloquei esta verificação no final.
A tabela também é gerada dinamicamente. Segue código:

```
var itemExtra   = itemExtra.split("|");
                var idExiste = false;
                var id = 0;
                while(idExiste == false){
                    id  = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1) + '_' + itemExtra[0].replace(' ', '');
                    if(document.getElementById(id) == null){
                        idExiste = true;
                    }
                }
                var table       = document.getElementById(tabela);
                var row         = table.insertRow(0);
                row.id          = id;
                var cell1       = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2       = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = itemExtra[1];
                var deletaExtra = document.createElement("INPUT");
                deletaExtra.setAttribute("type", "button");

                deletaExtra.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    deletaItemExtra(id.replace(" ",""));
                });

                deletaExtra.setAttribute("value", 'X');
                cell2.appendChild(deletaExtra);
```

Eu procurei e em alguns lugares disseram que poderia ser por conta das tds filhas, por isso eu estou deletando as duas.
Alguma sujestão?

Comment: Antes de tudo, o id deve começar com uma letra, depois pode utilizar o número que quiser, mas não pode ser apenas número. Faça essa adequação e veja se resolve, se não resolver, prosseguimos

Comment: Olá @BrunoRigolon, ajustei isso mas ainda não deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Você não está chamando a função. Isto:

```
document.getElementById(item).deleteRow
```

deveria ser:

```
document.getElementById(item).deleteRow(0);
```

ou simplesmente:

```
x.deleteRow(0);
```

Estou passando zero, que representa a primeira linha da tabela, pois não sei qual linha você quer excluir. Mas precisa passar o índice da linha a ser removida.

Comment: Olá @bfavaretto. Realmente estava errado. Mas ele ainda não funcionou. Ele não deveria receber algum parametro dentro dos parenteses? Tentei com 0 mas não deu certo. Agora ele está parando o script nesta linha.

Comment: Sim, precisa passar o índice da linha que você quer remover. 0 é a primeira linha, 1 é a segunda, etc.

Comment: Isso considerando que `item` seja a tabela.

Comment: Então, o item é o id da row. como ele retornaria apenas uma linha, ela seria o item 0 do indice. Mas se preciso percorrer toda a tabela, preciso mudar meu script.

Comment: Então faz assim @MatheusDelatorrre: `x.parentElement.removeChild(x)`

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado. Já estava fazendo um for pra percorrer a tabela.